# Working with Value Objects

Tags: c#, serialization, domain-driven-design, json.net

When developing I like to have strongly typed objects for certain values. An example could be a username. I've managed to create these value objects with validation of business rules in the constructor (the objects are immutable), but I when serializing these objects they behave funky.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Value}")]
public class Username
{
    private readonly string value;

    public Username(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentException("value", "Must have a value");

        if (value.Length > 50)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Maximum length of a username is 50");

        this.value = value;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Username username)
    {
        return username.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Username(string value)
    {
        return new Username(value);
    }
}
```

My question is: Using a serializer such as Newtonsoft Json.Net how go i get this value to be serialized as `{ Username:"foobar" }`?

Comment: "such as" is vague - I imagine *if possible* it will be different per implementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried this but I'd guess it support type converters.

Add the TypeConverter attrib to your class and create a converter for it (from string to username and vice versa)

Newtonsoft.json.net seems to support this:
http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Project/Json.NET/3.5-Release-6/Release/net-3.5/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ConvertUtils.cs

See the portion of the code starting with 
"// see if source or target types have a TypeConverter that converts ..."

Comment: If adding type converts to all my value objects is the answer then I'll question the value of having value objects in my code at all. It seems like a lot of work to do something as simple as this.

BUT! I do appreciate the answer! And it might even be the solution given the circumstances.

Comment: You could make a general type converter that always picks the data in ".Value" but say you have an value object like "Address" it will most likely have multiple properties, how would you want to serialize that?

Comment: As individual serialization of properties. The value objects on an address would be zipcode, country, etc. I wouldn't have an address.Value

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain '*behaves funky*'?

I don't have experience with Newtonsoft Json.Net, but typically serialisation/deserialisation needs:

1. Public **default constructors** on your objects
2. Property **setters**

However, I think you're mixing up 2 different problems here:

1. From a DDD perspective, you need an immutable Value Object (VO)
2. .NET allows you to create classes that support VO semantics
3. JSON.NET + .NET do **not** allow you to serialise your VOs

In a previous comment, you said:

> ...If adding type converts to all my
>   value objects is the answer then I'll
>   question the value of having value
>   objects in my code at all...

This is a flawed conclusion, because you're effectively saying:

*"I need VOs because they help ensure system integrity. But because I can't make the technology support VOs, I'm going to ignore this DDD concept i.e. **I'm going to ignore system integrity**."*

Not really an answer for you, but hopefully it will help you identify the *real* problem.

Comment: Json.NET doesn't require a default constructor. Json.NET attempts to use a parameter constructor if there is no default constructor. Parameter values will use the matching property value of the same name if available.

Comment: And this is valid way to deserialize immutable objects.